# Modeling peak Demand hours in Simpy

Tags: python, time, simpy

maybe this is really balant question but i couldnt find a solution yet.

I am simulating the charging behavior on a charging station. An easy process of either charging or waiting. I initialized the arrival through the expovariate function and it works like a charm. However, now I want to implement peak hours, in which arrival rates are changing.

since i need to simulate for a whole week, and the peak hours stay mainly the same i have implemented like this

```
def run_cs(env, num_charging_lots):
cs = CS(env, num_charging_lots)
ev = 1

while True:
    arrival_time = env.now
    if 2880 >= arrival_time > 1440:
        print('Tuesday')
    elif 4320 >= arrival_time > 2880:
        print('Wednesday')
    elif 5760 >= arrival_time > 4320:
        print('Thursday')
    elif 7200 >= arrival_time > 5760:
        print('Friday')
    elif 8640 >= arrival_time > 7200:
        print('Saturday')
    elif 10080 >= arrival_time > 8640:
        print('Sunday')

    hour = arrival_time / 60

    if (hour % 24) < 0.9 and hour != 0:
        print('es ist 0 Uhr')
        while (hour % 24) < 0.9:
            print('EV %s arrives at %d' % (ev, env.now))
            env.process(charging_EV(env, ev, cs))
            ev += 1
            yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(2))

    elif (hour % 7) < 0.9 and (hour != 0):
        print('es ist 7 Uhr')
        while (hour % 7) < 0.9 or 1440 <= (env.now % 1860) <= 1449 and (hour != 0):
            print('EV %s arrives at %d' % (ev, env.now))
            env.process(charging_EV(env, ev, cs))
            ev += 1
            yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1))

    elif (hour % 12) < 0.9 and (hour != 0):
        print('es ist 12 Uhr')
        while (hour % 12) < 0.9 and (hour != 0):
            print('EV %s arrives at %d' % (ev, env.now))
            env.process(charging_EV(env, ev, cs))
            ev += 1
            yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1))

    elif (hour % 18) < 0.9 or 1440 <= (env.now % 2520) <= 1449 and (hour != 0):
        while (hour % 18) < 0.9 and (hour != 0):
            print('EV %s arrives at %d' % (ev, env.now))
            env.process(charging_EV(env, ev, cs))
            ev += 1
            yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1))

    else:
        print('EV %s arrives at %d' % (ev, env.now))
        env.process(charging_EV(env, ev, cs))
        ev += 1
        yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(2))  # pace of EV arrivals
```

My Idea was to check if the current time is a peak time. That way the while loop for the time period starts and alters the arrival rate. if all fails the ordinary interarrival time should be used. My problem now is that the simualtion doesnt finish. My peak times are 0:00 or 12 Am, 7:00 / 7AM, 12:00/12PM and 18:00/6PM

Is there a better way to do it or to keep track of the hours of the day?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a infinite loop here

```
while (hour % 24) < 0.9:
        print('EV %s arrives at %d' % (ev, env.now))
        env.process(charging_EV(env, ev, cs))
        ev += 1
        yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(2))
```

where do you update your hour variable to break the while loop condition?
Same issue with your other while loops

or should all these while statements be if statements?

or do you even need the while statement, just do it once and let the outer loop do its thing